# Create this design with only NAND gates

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

[image]

How can I do that with NAND gates?

I have done this
[image]

with "blue" color if it doesn't seem well. It is A and C.

Comment: You can use the "dumb" approach - simply convert each gate into its implementation with `NAND`s. Sure if you can do some boolean algebra you can simplify it.

Comment: BTW, the gates on the left of your image are not NANDs, these are NANDs combined with inverters, effectively making them ORs

Comment: I know ,but I wanted to do the same result. I may influence them with inverters but I don't I use NAND gates right? I just wanted to get the same result.

Comment: Think a "direct wire" is equivalent to "2 serial inverter" ... Only place it at the right place, then reassemble.

Comment: @Antonio51 I didnt understand jesus

Comment: Add 2 bubbles located from nand output to OR input ( 2 times).
First AND and 1 bubble do  a NAND gate. Idem for 2nd And. OR gate and 1 bubble on each input make what ? A NAND gate ?

Comment: I tried to clear up the English. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Swap all 3 gates for Nand gates. That's all.

Comment: What says the "De Morgan theorems" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the first logical step would probably be to turn those AND gates into NAND gates, by adding two "bubbles" at the output of each.

[image]

Afterwards, review the concept of [Bubble Pushing](https://grace.bluegrass.kctcs.edu/%7Ekdunn0001/files/Simplification/4_Simplification10.html), then apply it in order to turn the rest of the components into NAND gates.

Comment: I'd have started by simply replacing the OR with a NAND that included two bubbles at its inputs, then pushed those bubbles leftwards to the AND gates to turn them into NAND. But right overall suggestion for the op. +1

Comment: you must do and the gate OR to nand gate too

Comment: @uriyaba you have OR gate.Only nand gates

Comment: @Yun.kon Plainly giving you the solution isn't what this site is about - I hinted at the right approach with my answer. Here's another hint - What's an equivalent component of an OR gate with 2 inverted inputs? [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) could help you.

Comment: I know ,but I can't get it. This is something more advance and I am not able to get it alone.Ok I got the one part of the replacement.I read De Morgan low but I can't understand how to replace the OR gate with a NAND gate.

Comment: The OR gate with the two inverting inputs can be represented as $$(X'+Y')$$ We can also write this down as $$[(X'+Y')']'$$ What does simplifying further, according to De Morgan's Laws, yield?

Comment: pretty easy X+Y. I still dont understand how to change the gate OR with NAND

Comment: @Yun.kon Not quite. What I meant was: $$(X'+Y')=[(X'+Y')']'=[XY]'$$
Which should look familiar :)

Comment: now you make me wonder. Let me ask and give me answer as the question so I will know what your answer is 1)if we go to the very first IMAGE.I have gates . I have a result AC+AB.This came from A*C , A * B on the OR gate. I add those A*C+A*B. That's my result.If I had another result(and it asked me to simplifie it ) THEN I what should do?De Morgan Or Boolean algebra? 2)I did boolean algebra I find the simplifie of lets call it X equation. Then I did Karnaugh map and I find the simplifier equation. 3)Should I have used de morgan? 4)can I not work with de morgan and to solve with the way I did?

Comment: @Yun.kon The approach depends on the question, I was just suggesting the most intuitive way to solve. Bubble pushing and De Morgan's Laws and generally the best way to solve these type of questions. Both the laws and K-Maps are based on the basics of Boolean Algebra, so technically, you **could** solve it in other ways, but they're more cumbersome.

Comment: @uriyaba thank you for your answer

Comment: @Yun.kon You're welcome! I encourage you to upvote it as well as accept it.